# django packages need instruction

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, pinax, web-development-server

I am looking for interactive online courses about Django similar to ones on Codecademy.com for php, ruby, javascript, etc, or www.codeschool.com for ruby, javascript, etc. I've done the toy tutorial on https://www.djangoproject.com.  But it doesn't really help me in terms of real production work.

I've also gone on youtube to look for information, but the video tutorials are very basic.  For example, how do I use or incorporate the numerous django packages at https://www.djangopackages.com/  to my working project? I see the docs (when one exist for a specific package), but they don't go into details on how to merge that app into an existing project. Also, another example, is that I want to use django with twitter-bootstrap and found out that most developers use pinax, but I couldn't find a decent guide on using that app.

I'm new to Django and I would love to find some videos or online tutorial on how to use Django in real world situation (specifically, examples mentioned above).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there are quite a few misconceptions. Most Django developers do not use Pinax (although some certainly do).

Second, most apps I've come across will explain in their docs how to install them. Have a look at using [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) for the actual installing. Bootstrap can be used as is, or via apps like  [django-bootstrap-toolkit](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit)

For a good introduction to django check out [Getting Started With Django.](http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/) It'll cover most of what you're talking about.

Comment: "Getting Started with Django" is an excellent source.  It begins where the Polls project left off.  Regarding django-bootstrap-toolkit, is that the most common app layout django users prefer? Or is there another plug-n-play apps that comes with batteries?  Could you give some additional tips on some additional resources to help new django enthusiast like me to get my website up and running quickly? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Django Bootstrap toolkit is twitter bootstrap made easy (for django of course).

Comment: @user2424253 If you're curious about best practices, I would complete Getting Started with Django then read Two Scoops of Django. Easily the best best practices book on the market. Maybe a little advanced for the beginner but a worthy purchase for everyone. https://django.2scoops.org/